# How to build dynamic variables in python

Tags: python-3.x

I need to build dynamic variables in python. I mean like `b=3` and `a=b-3`. All of us know **a** is **0** now and when I change **b**, **a** doesn't change but i want **a** changes to.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question. I'm not sure this is really a paradigm that makes sense in Python. You could define your own class and override all the basic arithmetic operations but that could be rather complicated. An easier option might be to use a function. You'll have to call it as `a()` rather than `a` but other than that it does what you want.

```
def a():
    return b-3
```